# Cycle among table cells, reading different data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Here my HTML table:

```
<table id="tableSensors" class="table table-sm header-fixed">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Min</th>
            <th scope="col" width="10%">Max</th>
            <th scope="col" width="10%">Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Temperature</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="21" readonly="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Humidity</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="65" readonly="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pressure</td>
            <td>980</td>
            <td>1040</td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="1015" readonly="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The first row is to implement a filter, so it does not contain useful data.
The last column has an `input` tag, rather then a plain text.

I want to:

1. cycle among all rows/column
2. skipping the first row
3. pushing data into an array, keeping in mind the difference of the last column

This is the actual code:

```
function exportTable(id) { // id = #tableSensors
    let data = [];
    $(id).find('tr').not(':first').each(function() {
        $(this).find('td').each(function() {
            data.push($(this).text().trim());
        });
    });

    // do something else
}
```

But:

1. it does not skip the first row
2. I'm not sure how to know if I'm in the last column to use `.val()` on the `input` tag

Ideally, I should check in each cell if there is an `input` tag to retrieve the data in the right way.

### UPDATE

Second point fixed by myself:

```
$(id).find('tr').not(':first').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('input').length) data.push($(this).find('input').val().trim());
        else data.push($(this).text().trim());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter within the `tbody` otherwise it will ignore the tr within `thead` since [`:first` pseudo class selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selects the first one among the entire collection.

```
function exportTable(id) { // id = #tableSensors
  let data = [];
  $(id).find('tbody tr').not(':first').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      data.push($(this).text().trim());
    });
  });

  console.log(data);
  // do something else
}
```

```js
function exportTable(id) { // id = #tableSensors
  let data = [];
  $('table tbody').find('tr').not(':first').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      data.push($(this).text().trim());
    });
  });

  console.log(data);
  // do something else
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableSensors" class="table table-sm header-fixed">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Min</th>
      <th scope="col" width="10%">Max</th>
      <th scope="col" width="10%">Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Temperature</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="21" readonly="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Humidity</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="65" readonly="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pressure</td>
      <td>980</td>
      <td>1040</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="1015" readonly="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<span onClick="exportTable();">click</span>
```

---

You can use [`:first-child][2]` as well which will work in both ways since it ignores both tr elements.

```
function exportTable(id) { // id = #tableSensors
  let data = [];
  $(id).find('tbody tr:not(:first-child)').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      data.push($(this).text().trim());
    });
  });

}
```

```js
function exportTable(id) { // id = #tableSensors
  let data = [];
  $('table tbody tr:not(:first-child)').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      data.push($(this).text().trim());
    });
  });


  console.log(data);
  // do something else
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableSensors" class="table table-sm header-fixed">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Min</th>
      <th scope="col" width="10%">Max</th>
      <th scope="col" width="10%">Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Temperature</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="21" readonly="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Humidity</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="65" readonly="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pressure</td>
      <td>980</td>
      <td>1040</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" value="1015" readonly="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<span onClick="exportTable();">click</span>
```

Comment: Oh yes. It was simple.